# Android: How to make sure an EditText never loses focus?

Tags: android, android-edittext, autofocus

I'm writing an app that gets input from a barcode scanner. The scanner is simply registered as a keyboard with the Android OS. Thus it will simply 'type' whatever barcode it reads into the currently focused EditText.

I have no plan to have any other EditText in my app. 
I set AutoFocus to true, and it works for now.

But are there scenarios/events where it could lose focus (changing the app, user making a screenshot,...)?

Because I want to hide away my EditText and the user wouldn't have a chance to refocus it himself. My users are very non-techy people that get a readily setup device that only uses this app, so I want to hide away from them how this works.

Comment: write edit text focuschangelistner , and in that  write edittext.requestfocus()

Comment: @fancy, How you are resolved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, I didn't test yet ,but I think this should work

```
 edit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!edit.hasFocus()){
            edit.requestFocus();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
edit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!edit.hasFocus()){
            edit.requestFocus();
        }

    }
});
```